# $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ ~$N(\mu_{1}, \sigma^2)$ and $y_1, \cdots, y_n$ ~ $N(\mu_{2}, \sigma^{2})$ Find Restricted Likelihood Estimators

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

So the goal is to test the hypothesis

$H_0: \mu_{1}=\mu_{2}$

$H_1: \mu_{1} \neq \mu_{2}$

I've already found the full likelihood function, and the unrestricted MLE's which is just the normal MLE's (maximum likelihood estimators). But in order for me to use the generalized likelihood ratio statistic I need to find the restricted MLE's. The question is

"Find the restricted maximum likelihood estimators of $\mu$, the common value of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and $\sigma^2$ restricted under $H_0$."

How would I go about doing this because this was the last thing he taught us before our exam but never show us how to find the actual restricted estimators.

Answer (score 0):

Might be I misunderstood what you are aiming, but maybe you should rewrite your problem as:

$$
\mu_2 = \mu_1 + \mu
$$

and then test

$$
H_0 : \mu = 0
$$

$$
H_1 : \mu \neq 0
$$

Then you could try to find the unconditional ($\mu$ is minimized) and conditional ($\mu$ is fixed) MLEs.
Is the goal to perform a likelihood ratio test ?

Comment: Im not sure. I do know that for the normal MLE it's not restricted, but for the restricted MLE you have to restrict under the null hypothesis and so the normal MLE is max of the entire space and then the restricted MLE is the max of the space just under the null. I hope that made sense, this is at least what I'm getting from my materials but I'm still not sure

Comment: Ok, then we said the same. For the restricted MLE, $\mu$ is set to 0, and then you minimize the likelihood wrt the remaining (nuisance) parameters i.e. $\mu_1$ and $\sigma$.

Answer (score 0):

A hint:

Under $H_0$, the distribution for $y_i$ and $x_i$ are identical (i.e. $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$), where $\mu=\mu_1=\mu_2$. Thus, you need to find (assuming $x$ and $y$ are independent):

$$
\sup_{\mu} L(\mu;\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x})=\sup_{\mu} f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}; \mu)=\sup_{\mu} \left(f(\mathbf{x}; \mu) f(\mathbf{y}; \mu)\right)
$$
which means that you should solve the following for $\mu$:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\left\{\log L(\mu;\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x})\right\}&=0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\left\{2\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\right)^n-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mu)^2\right\}&=0
\end{align}
$$
since 
$$
f(\mathbf{x}; \mu) f(\mathbf{y}; \mu)=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x_i-\mu)^2\right\}\right)\times\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y_i-\mu)^2\right\}\right).
$$